# pip can't find django 3.x - ERROR: No matching distribution found for django==3.0.4

Tags: python, django, pip, django-3.0

When I run:

```
pip3 install django==3.0.5
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==3.0.5 (from versions: 1.1.3, ... 2.2.11, 2.2.12) ERROR: No matching distribution found for django==3.0.4
```

I need to update some references somewhere, but I am not sure how. Plz Help.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Django 3.x only supports Python 3.6+

Comment: Im on python 3.5 .. maybe this is it.

Comment: update your pip

Comment: With python 3.7 it worked correctly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in the comments, Django 3.x is [only available for Python 3.6 or greater](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django). If you attempt to install Django 3 while using an older version of Python (e.g. Python 3.5 in the case of the OP), pip will be unable to find a matching package.

The solution is to simply upgrade to a more modern version of Python.

Comment: This is especially tricky with current Django versions (4.0+): They **need Python 3.8+** to run and be installed, and many operating systems are still stuck with Python 3.6 or 3.7. When you use a Python version lower than that to run `pip install` (on your local machine) then **only compatible versions are listed**. That's tricky and - arguably - misleading. If your operating system doesn't provide a Python version > 3.8 you may want to use something like `pyenv` to install any Python version you need. See https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation for the official docs.

Answer (score 4):

You got the version wrong... The latest official version is 3.0.5. Do instead

```
pip install Django==3.0.5
```

Read more about it [here](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/).

---

### Update

After the new comments was able to se you're using Python 3.5. thing is, according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/faq/install/#faq-python-version-support), for to use Django version 3.0.x one needs Python version 3.6, 3.7 or 3.8.

So, as a Linux user and assuming you can simply update to a newer version, you can use the terminal with the following commands to get a newer version of Python (for instances, 3.7.0 version)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3.7
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. I copied it correctly, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Test again because the error you also pasted shows a wrong version...

Comment: Ok, I corrected it. the pip line is correct. It is the repository reference I need to change somewhere. ... I'm on a bright new Ubuntu, installed it yesterday.

Comment: if You are on ubuntu, please also check maybe you got `pip3` because sometimes there are two versions installed

Comment: @Take_Care_ tried it with pip3 and got the same error

Comment: When I run `py --version`, I get `Python 3.8.8`, but when I run `py -m pip install Django`, I get `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django` and `ERROR: No matching distribution found for Django`. Is Python 3.8.8 not enough to install the latest Django? What am I missing?

Comment: @Joshua did you try `pip install Django==3.0.5`?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres I did. I get the exact same errors... Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Python version you have installed is not supporting by that Django version.